# Union and union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Union all is giving the right result and union is giving a wrong result.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT TOP 20 * 
          FROM noble_win 
         WHERE [YEAR ] = 1970 
           AND [SUBJECT   ]  NOT IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry') 
        ORDER BY [SUBJECT   ],[WINNER                ]) AS A
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT TOP 20 * 
          FROM noble_win 
         WHERE [YEAR ]=1970 
           AND [SUBJECT   ] IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry') 
        ORDER BY [SUBJECT   ],[WINNER                ]) AS B
```

This query is giving rows `Chemistry` and `Economics` first and then rows other than `Economics` and `Chemistry`. However, I want rows other than `Economics` and `Chemistry` first. I do not know why it is giving the wrong result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ORDER BY` has to be applied at the outermost query level:

```
select  * from 
(select top 20 *,1 AS ord from noble_win 
 where [YEAR ]=1970 and [SUBJECT   ]  NOT IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry')
 order by [SUBJECT   ],[WINNER                ]
)  as A
union 
select * from 
(select top 20 *, 2 AS ord from noble_win 
 where [YEAR ]=1970 and [SUBJECT   ] IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry')
 order by [SUBJECT   ],[WINNER                ]
) as B
order by ord, [SUBJECT   ],[WINNER                ])
```

---

And you are the winner of DBA Revenge contest:  identifiers with spaces.

**[Revenge: The SQL!](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event12/Revenge_The_SQL)**

> **Naming Conventions**
>
> - Reserved
> - **Blanks**
> - Hidden
> - Duplicate
> - Unicode

Comment: Goodness!  Not just spaces, but TRAILING spaces.    I wonder if it is a bizarre security measure.   :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yup, but still level2 - not great, not terrible. It could be much worse. For instance using [unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(Cyrillic)) that looks the same - **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b16a0d77459ad53e37f9aa4f5f784f12)**

Comment: Thanks @LukaszSzozda it worked. I was not able to understand why it is  giving me chemistry in the first row when I mentioned not in(chemistry, economics) in first statement of the query. It was because I have to mention order by in the outermost query which I didnot do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional sorting with a CASE statement:

```
select * from (
  select top 20 * from noble_win 
  where [YEAR]=1970 and [SUBJECT] NOT IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry') 
  order by [SUBJECT], [WINNER]
) t1
union all
select * from (
  select top 20 * from noble_win 
  where [YEAR]=1970 and [SUBJECT] IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry')
  order by [SUBJECT], [WINNER] 
) t2
order by 
  case when [SUBJECT] NOT IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry') then 1 else 2 end,
  [SUBJECT], 
  [WINNER]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `union`/`union all` then the `order by` has to be on the outermost select.  However, you don't need them.  You can just use expressions and window functions:

```
select nw.* 
from (select nw.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year,
                                             (case when [SUBJECT   ] in ('Economics', 'Chemistry') then 1 else 2 end)
                                order by [SUBJECT   ], [WINNER                ])
                               ) as seqnum
      from noble_win nw
     ) nw
where seqnum <= 20
order by (case when [SUBJECT   ] in ('Economics', 'Chemistry') then 1 else 2 end) desc,
         [WINNER                ]);
```

And fix you column names!